# Using XML to populate Model not a Database

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, mvvm

I have recently began my journey learning WPF and MVVM. However a lot of guides and discussions I have found have been with the MVVM Data accessing at Database.

I simply want to be able to load a XML file instead of going through a Database but I don't have much knowledge in the area or the best practice of using a XML as a Data source in MVVM.

Any help what so ever would be appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of ways and depending on your application it may be different.  You may want to start with DataSet.ReadXml() method or DataTable.ReadXml() method.

Comment: So you mean to say Load the XML using XDocument and putting into a DataSet or DataTable?

Comment: See my updated code.

Comment: Do you have a example of calling these methods in MVVM. I only ask cause it will make my head understand it more.

And those methods should be called in the Data Layer correct? not View Model.

Comment: Reading an Xml into a DataSet/DataTable only works well when the number of tag layers are small.  For xml where the number of layers is large it is better to parse the xml in code.              DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("filename");

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with WPF or MVVM.  If you are only attempting to research loading/parsing/saving XML within this context, it's no wonder you can't find anything.  Simply research how to load, parse and save xml using c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't appear to have anything to do with WPF or MVVM, it looks like your questions are related to using XML for data access. One such way is [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)?

```
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(filename);

var data = (from item in xmlDocument.Descendants()
            select new
            {
                Customers = (from customers in item.Descendants("Customer")
                             select new Customer
                             {
                                 Name = customers.Element("Name").Value,
                                 Address = customers.Element("Address").Value
                             }).ToList(),
                Manufacturers = (from manufacturers in item.Descendants("Manufacturer")
                                 select new Manufacturer
                                 {
                                     Name = manufacturers.Element("Name").Value,
                                     Phone = manufacturers.Element("Phone").Value
                                 }).ToList()
            }).SingleOrDefault();
```